Issue with FFmpeg in Docker Container: "Failed to Resolve Hostname" for RTMP Stream
I am trying to set up a Docker environment where I use an NGINX RTMP server and a PHP container to stream video to YouTube Live using HLS files. The setup involves sharing volumes between the containers and using FFmpeg within the PHP container to start the live stream. However, I am encountering an issue where FFmpeg fails to resolve the hostname when attempting to connect to YouTube's RTMP server.
Setup Details:
Docker Compose Configuration:
docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  rtmp:
    image: tiangolo/nginx-rtmp
    ports:
      - "1935:1935"
    volumes:
      - shared_data:/usr/share/nginx/hls
      - ./conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  php:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - shared_data:/var/www/html/hls
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined

volumes:
  shared_data:

Dockerfile
FROM php:apache
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
RUN curl -O https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-amd64-static.tar.xz && \
    tar -xJf ffmpeg-release-amd64-static.tar.xz && \
    mv ffmpeg-*/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/ && \
    mv ffmpeg-*/ffprobe /usr/local/bin/ && \
    rm -rf ffmpeg-*

./conf/nginx.conf
worker_processes auto;
rtmp_auto_push on;
events {}
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        listen [::]:1935 ipv6only=on;
        access_log /var/log/rtmp_access.log;
        chunk_size 4096;
        timeout 10s;

        application live {
            live on;
            record off;


            hls on;
            hls_path /usr/share/nginx/hls;
            hls_fragment 10s;
        }
    }
}

Using nginx container to receive rtmp from camera(gopro).
The php container provides a UI for streaming management, etc., and distribution via ffmpeg.
Received hls is shared by docke's shared volume.
Failed FFmpeg Command:
ffmpeg -re -i "/var/www/html/hls/.m3u8" -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 -flags +global_header -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -bufsize 3000k -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/live_key"

Error Message
[tcp @ 0x696d2c0] Failed to resolve hostname a.rtmp.youtube.com: System error
[rtmp @ 0x696d480] Cannot open connection tcp://a.rtmp.youtube.com:1935?tcp_nodelay=0
[out#0/flv @ 0x6890880] Error opening output rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/live_key: Input/output error
Error opening output file rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/live_key.
Error opening output files: Input/output error

Success FFmpeg Command:
ffmpeg -re -i "/var/www/html/hls/.m3u8" -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 -flags +global_header -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -bufsize 3000k -f flv "rtmp://74.125.203.134/live2/live_key"

Not use domain but ip.
What I Have Tried:

Running FFmpeg on Host:

I installed FFmpeg on my host machine (macOS) and ran the below command, which worked without any issues, indicating that the problem is specific to the Docker container environment.
ffmpeg -re -i "http://localhost:8080/hls/.m3u8" -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -strict -2 -flags +global_header -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/live_key"


DNS Resolution:

Inside the PHP container, I ran nslookup a.rtmp.youtube.com and got multiple IP addresses, which suggests that DNS resolution should work:
nslookup a.rtmp.youtube.com
Server:         240b:11:cc40:d500:23a:9dff:fe92:75a8
Address:        240b:11:cc40:d500:23a:9dff:fe92:75a8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   a.rtmp.youtube.com
Address: 74.125.203.134
...

What could be causing the DNS resolution issue within the Docker container when using FFmpeg to stream to YouTube Live? How can I resolve this so that the domain name works correctly in the FFmpeg command within the Docker container?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

the 7.0.1 version of ffmpeg indicates a change about DNS.

A limitation of statically linking glibc is the loss of DNS resolution. Installing
nscd through your package manager will fix this.

https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/release-readme.txt
Do you have the same issue with a previous version of ffmpeg?
Some solutions are suggested here: FFMPEG "Segmentation fault" with network stream source
